# Yaesu FT-857D VFO scan won't stop

Tags: yaesu

I have set ny Yaesu FT857-D to PMS scan of the 144-148MHz FM ham band, but it doesn't seem to find anything. 
However, I see the green "busy" light come on every once in a while during the scanning, but the scan doesn't stop.
The other strange thing is that turning the squelch down to zero has no effect on the scan, either. (Although I can open the squelch when tuned into a particular frequency)
Anyone have any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, I suspect the problem is that you have tone squelch (`TSQ`) enabled. In this mode, the audio is muted unless the signal contains the proper tone, but the receive light will still light up to indicate a non-matching signal is present. (This is true outside of scanning too.)

Go to Multi Function Row `MFe` and press the <kbd>A</kbd> `TON` button to cycle through encode/squelch modes to the blank position. (If the button is labeled `ENC` instead of `TON`, then in menu mode set `079 SPLIT TONE` to `OFF` first.)

Comment: Checked that. TON was already in the blank position. The scanner still goes right past any signal, with only the green light coming on to show it is there.

Comment: Also, this problem only occurs in the 2m band (144-148MHz). When I try the VFO scanning in 430-440MHz, the scan stops when I detect a signal or open the squelch.